Run Drools Scenario tests automatically in a maven build
I have a large number of scenario test files that test a large number of drools rules used in an application.
Is there any way of including the scenario tests in a Maven build so they get executed automatically, similar to Unit tests are.
I'm trying to look at using drools-workbench-models-test-scenarios (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-workbench-models-test-scenarios) but the support around it seems to be sparse, and I may be looking in the wrong place.
Does anybody have experience with this?

I've never used this particular tool (drools-scenario) and do my Drools testing via unit tests, but anything that you can invoke from the commandline you can also invoke via a Maven plugin -- not necessarily something specific for the tool but one of the general plugins like maven-ant or exec-maven or similar.
